# Entity Framework update many-to-many relation in new DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relation between groups and users. I would like to load elements from a DBContext, modify them, and then attach them to a new DBContext (for various reason it is not a good solution to keep the context alive between loading and saving).

In the code below I have recreated the scenario, but for some reason reattaching and saving doesn't seem to work.

```
public class TUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TGroup> Groups { get; set; } = new List<TGroup>();
}

public class TGroup
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroupDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UserGroupDbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TGroup> Groups { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Groups)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("GroupId");
                m.ToTable("UserGroup");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class UserRepositoryTest
{
    public UserRepositoryTest()
    {
        var group1 = new TGroup();
        var group2 = new TGroup();
        var group3 = new TGroup();
        var user = new TUser { Groups = new List<TGroup> { group1, group2 } };

        var dbContextFixture = new DbContextFixture<UserGroupDbContext>();
        using (var dbContext = dbContextFixture.CreateContext())
        {
            dbContext.Groups.Add(group1);
            dbContext.Groups.Add(group2);
            dbContext.Groups.Add(group3);
            dbContext.Users.Add(user);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        user.Groups.Remove(group2);
        user.Groups.Add(group3);

        using (var dbContext = dbContextFixture.CreateContext())
        {
            dbContext.Users.Attach(user);

            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var dbContext = dbContextFixture.CreateContext())
        {
            var loadedUser = dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Groups).Single();
            Assert.True(loadedUser.Groups.Any(g => g.Id == group1.Id));
            Assert.True(loadedUser.Groups.Any(g => g.Id == group3.Id)); // <-- This line fails
            Assert.False(loadedUser.Groups.Any(g => g.Id == group2.Id)); // <-- This line fails
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify your entity before Attaching to Context, the Context will not be aware of modification. You should either modify entity after attaching or set it's State to Modified

[Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state#attaching-an-existing-but-modified-entity-to-the-context)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

I would like to accept Buram Hajrizaj's answer aswell.

Answer (score 1):

When you have one already loaded entity and from another DBContext and want to change it with another DBContext than you need to attach you Model into your new DBContext.

This happens since you new DbConext can not know if something changes since it can not keep track of it.

Se the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Hope this helps